# Copy a executed dynamic html to a static html

Tags: javascript, html, curl, wget

the problem is as follows:
I have a html with several "id's" which are permanently filled with data by a javascript program. I need a hard copy of the html file every second. I know I could do this with wget or curl but both just copy the html file without the data in it. Is there a possibility to use something like wget or curl to copy the "filled" html (after executing the java script) ?

thanks in advance

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: There is no such thing as “a java script.”  A Java program is not a script.  JavaScript is the name of an entirely different language.  Normally I wouldn’t be pedantic about grammar, but in this case it is not clear which language you want to use.

Comment: sorry  i already edited the question. it is a javascript program which queries a mqtt server for data. The html script just is a table with different columns, marked by "id's". The java program writes the data into the columns by using the respective id.